# Need to custom attribute in customer info backend programatically for magento 2

Tags: magento2

[image]

I need to add custom attribute same as image in `backend` in customer information to individual customer. If admin select category customer able to show only selected category.

```
namespace Metizsoft\Allowcustomer\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;

class Category implements ArrayInterface{

    protected $_categoryHelper;
    protected $categoryRepository;
    protected $categoryList;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $catalogCategory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository
        )
    {
        $this->_categoryHelper = $catalogCategory;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    }

    /*
     * Return categories helper
     */

    public function getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true)
    {
        return $this->_categoryHelper->getStoreCategories($sorted , $asCollection, $toLoad);
    }

    /*  
     * Option getter
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {


        $arr = $this->toArray();
        $ret = [];

        foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
        {

            $ret[] = [
                'value' => $key,
                'label' => $value
            ];
        }

        return $ret;
    }

    /*
     * Get options in "key-value" format
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray()
    {

        $categories = $this->getStoreCategories(true,false,true);
        $categoryList = $this->renderCategories($categories);
        return $categoryList;
    }

    public function renderCategories($_categories)
    {
        foreach ($_categories as $category){
            $i = 0; 
            $this->categoryList[$category->getEntityId()] = __($category->getName());   // Main categories
            $list = $this->renderSubCat($category,$i);
        }

        return $this->categoryList;     
    }

    public function renderSubCat($cat,$j){

        $categoryObj = $this->categoryRepository->get($cat->getId());

        $level = $categoryObj->getLevel();
        $arrow = str_repeat("---", $level-1);
        $subcategories = $categoryObj->getChildrenCategories(); 

        foreach($subcategories as $subcategory) {
            $this->categoryList[$subcategory->getEntityId()] = __($arrow.$subcategory->getName()); 

            if($subcategory->hasChildren()) {

                $this->renderSubCat($subcategory,$j);

            }
        } 

        return $this->categoryList;
    }
}
```

Comment: What you have tried so far. Please post those details. Also, kindly don't post fill requirement on the question. At least give some try your self

Comment: @Amit Bera, i have created file for select category like image but in not work look above code

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface` type for as Source  Model of a multi-select EAV attribute.

> Metizsoft\Allowcustomer\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\HideCategory

Should be extended `\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource` or your class will be the interface of `Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface`.

**InstallData.php code attribute  create code must have source model and backend model that**

```
    $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'hide_category', [
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'label' => 'Hide Categories',
        'input' => 'multiselect',
        'source' => 'Metizsoft\Allowcustomer\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\HideCategory',
        'required' => false,
        'visible' => true,
        'position' => 333,
        'system' => false,
        'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend'
    ]);
```

**Source Model Class code**

```
<?php


namespace Metizsoft\Allowcustomer\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source;

class HideCategory extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory
     */
    private $collectionFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category
     */
    private $catalogCategory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $catalogCategory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory    
    ) {

        $this->catalogCategory = $catalogCategory;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }
    /**
     * getAllOptions
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $options = $this->optionDataInArray();
        array_unshift($options, ['value' => '', 'label' => __('Please Selec')]);
        $this->_options = $options;

        return $options;
    }
    public function optionDataInArray(): array {

        $categories = $this->catalogCategory->getStoreCategories(true, false, true) ; 
        $options = [];
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $options[] = ['value' => $category->getId(), 'label' => $category->getName()];
            $options =$this->secondLevelCategories($category->getId(),$category->getName(),$options);
        }
        return $options;
    }
    private function secondLevelCategories($parentCatId,$parentCatName,$options)
    {

       $categoryCollection =  $this->collectionFactory->create();
       $categoryCollection->addAttributeToSelect(
            'url_key'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'name'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'all_children'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'is_anchor'
        )->addAttributeToFilter(
            'parent_id',
            $parentCatId
        )->addAttributeToFilter(
            'is_active',
            1
        )->setOrder(
            'position',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Select::SQL_ASC
        )->joinUrlRewrite();

       foreach($categoryCollection as $category){
           $options[] = ['value' => $category->getId(), 'label' => $parentCatName.'-->'. $category->getName()];
       }
       return $options;
    }    
}
```

***Also, your module must have below files & folders structure.***

[image]

**InstallData.php full code**

```
<?php

namespace Metizsoft\Allowcustomer\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'hide_category', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Hide Categories',
            'input' => 'multiselect',
            'source' => 'Metizsoft\Allowcustomer\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\HideCategory',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'position' => 333,
            'system' => false,
            'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend'
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'hide_category')
        ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'customer_account_create',
                'customer_account_edit'
            ]
        ]);
        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

**Output on magento 2 sample data Instance**
[image]

Comment: hello 

why we used extension_attributes.xml
i am not understand about it can you able to give that file code

Comment: extension attribute need to enable your attribute for API